# javascript - unable to change object position

Tags: javascript, position

```
var img = new Image();
img.className = "block";
img.src = "http://db.tt/xCGgJN48";
img.style.left = x + "px";
img.style.top = y + "px";
var array = [];
array.push(img);
document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(array[0]);
//imagine some delay here
array[0].style.left = (array[0].style.left + 10) + "px";
```

i cant get the image to move. btw thats not the actual code, the last line of code is whats not moving it and i have other bits of code in between. whats wrong with it??

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with arrays.

Comment: well no, but i didnt know what was going on at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code is where the issue is:

```
(array[0].style.left + 10) + "px";
```

`array[0].style.left` is returning something like `100px`. So, adding `10` to that will be `100px10`, and then adding `px` to that will be `100px10px`. What you need to do is use `parseInt` to covert the `100px` to `100`, and then adding `10` will be `110`, and adding `px` to that will give you the correct `110px`.

```
array[0].style.left = parseInt(array[0].style.left) + 10 + "px";
```

Comment: yea, at some point i was wondering why we had to add all these "px" to everything and whether changing it would be weird. i added the parseInt but i get " --- Missing radix parameter."

Comment: `parseInt(array[0].style.left, 10)`. The radix is usually optional... strange that you're getting that error. A radix is the number system you're using. For example, `10` is decimal, and `2` is binary.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that, and what is a radix. im quite a beginner.

Comment: If you need any more information about `parseInt`, you can read this :-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Be sure to check the checkmark when someone answers your question successfully. Welcome to StackOverflow :)